# How to disable 'F1' in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

In Eclipse's Preference's keys, it's allowed to set <kbd>F1</kbd> binding for any key. However, it seems that <kbd>F1</kbd> is preserved for triggering 'Help'.

All non-newbies need <kbd>F1</kbd> very rarely, so this takes up a valuable place on the keyboard which is convenient for user defined Eclipse keys.

Is it possible to disable <kbd>F1</kbd> in Eclipse? If it is, how to disable it?

Comment: thanks a lot. This question is of great help